# Rectangle not moving

Tags: java, timer, move, rectangles

Hello I'm trying to create a brick breaker game. There is a main class called Real_Main and another class called Real_Create that extends JPanel. I feel like my code is right but I can't seem to move my rectangle with the right and left arrow keys. Could anyone tell me what's wrong with it? And why do we need a timer to move the rectangle?

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class Real_Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JFrame jf= new JFrame();

        Real_Create panel=new Real_Create();

        jf.setSize(500, 500);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setResizable(false);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.add(panel);

    }

}
```

Real_Create:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Real_Create extends JPanel implements KeyListener,ActionListener {

     int baseX=200;

    int ballX=250;
    int ballY=250;
    int delay=20;

    Timer tim;


    Boolean play=false;


    public Real_Create(){

        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);

        tim=new Timer(delay,this);

        tim.start();

    }


    public void paint(Graphics g){

        //background
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(1,1,500,500 );

        //baseplayer

        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(baseX, 430, 80, 10);

        //ball
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillOval(ballX, ballY, 20, 20);


        g.dispose();




    }



    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        tim.start();
        repaint();

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){

            if(baseX >=420){

                baseX=420;
            }

            else{

                moveRight();
            }

        }

         if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){

            if(baseX <=0){

                baseX=0;
            }

            else{

                moveLeft();
            }

        }


    }




    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

public void moveRight(){

        play=true;
        baseX+=10;
    }

    public void moveLeft(){

        play=true;
        baseX-=10;
    }
}
```

Image from the game:

[image: Image from the game]

Comment: I just tested your code, and for me moving the rect works flawlessly. It might only be because of your screenshot program, but in the image the window does not have focus. It needs to have focus for the keylistener to work, try clicking the window. 
Also, you don't necessarily need a timer for moving the rect, at the moment it only redraws the window every 20 ms, you could just as well call repaint after a key press, but it will be usefull when you try to animate the ball.

Answer (score 0):

What you are dealing with is unpredictable Swing behaviour due to its lack of thread safety. According to documentation "all code that creates or interacts with Swing components must run on the event dispatch thread". To achieve that you should rewrite your GUI creation like so:

```
public class Real_Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }

  private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame jf = new JFrame();
    Real_Create panel = new Real_Create();
    jf.setSize(500, 500);
    jf.setVisible(true);
    jf.setResizable(false);
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.add(panel);
  }
}
```

You can read more on the subject [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).